# erro NullPointerException com composição de classes

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Eu tenho uma classe chamada Users, que possui como atributo um vetor do tipo Sensors

```
protected Sensors sensors[10];
```

Ela também tem o método setDescription

```
public void setDescription (int ind, String description)
{
    this.sensors[ind].description = description;
}
```

Depois de instanciar um objeto chamado user,  tentei chamar pelo método assim:

```
user.setDescription (ctr, description);
```

mas tá dando NullPointerException. Se alguém puder me ajudar, fico agradecido.

Comment: Só com isso não dá para ajudar muito. Uma coisa que você pode fazer é verificar se o objeto `sensors` é nulo antes de acessá-lo, mas não vai adiantar muito, não resolve o problema de fato. Precisa ver o resto da classe porque ele não está inicializado ou algum elemento do *array* não está inicializado. Provavelmente você precisa inicializar no construtor mas não posso afirmar só com estas informações.

Comment: bem, estou chamando o construtor assim: user.sensors[ctr] = new Sensors(name2, description); mas não sei se está correto

Comment: O problema é o código que está dentro do construtor. Como eu falei se você não colocar todo seu código, vai ser difícil identificar onde está seu problema. Vou mostrou o sintoma, a causa está oculta.

Answer (score 2):

Isso aconteceu pois o atributo `protected Sensors sensors[10]` não foi inicializado.

Você pode fazer isso, ou no construtor ou na própria declaração do atributo, dessa maneira: `protected Sensors[] sensors = new Sensors[10];`

Comment: Caso a resposta tenha resolvido seu problema, por favor, a marque como correta clicando na seta verde abaixo das setas da questão.